# Are there infinitely many primes which are factors of no terms in the sequence $a_0 = 4$, $a_{n}=$ $a_{n-1}^{2}-a_{n-1}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, solution-verification, recurrence-relations, contest-math

Problem statement:

> Let $a_{0}=4$ and define a sequence of terms using the formula $a_{n}=$ $a_{n-1}^{2}-a_{n-1}$ for each positive integer $n$
>
> a) Prove that there are infinitely many prime numbers which are factors of at least one term in the sequence;
>
> b) Are there infinitely many prime numbers which are factors of no term in the sequence?

My attempted proof is as follows:

a) Write $a_n = a_{n-1} (a_{n-1} - 1)$. If a prime $p$ divides $a_{n-1}$ then $p$ cannot divide $a_{n-1} - 1$, else $p$ would divide their difference, $1$. So there must exist another prime $p_1 \ne p$ such that $p_1 \mid (a_{n-1} - 1)$ which implies $p_1 \mid a_n$. Similarly, since $p$ and $p_1$ both divide $a_n$, neither can divide $a_n - 1$, so $\exists p_2 \ne p,p_1$ such that $p_2 \mid a_{n+1}$. Continuing in this way we generate an infinite sequence of distinct primes $(p_k)_k$ where $p_k \mid a_{n+k-1}$.

b) I noticed that if $a_N \cong 2 \pmod p$ for some $N$, then $a_n \cong 2 \pmod p$ for all $n \ge N$ by the recurrence relation, since $2\times(2-1) = 2$. Clearly such a prime cannot be a divisor of any term in the sequence, for if it were, each term in the sequence thereafter would be congruent to $0 \pmod p$. It thus suffices to find infinitely many primes $p$ such that $a_n \cong 2 \pmod p$ for at least one term in the sequence. If we define a new sequence $b_n = a_n - 2$ then this is equivalent to finding infinitely many primes $p$ which are factors of at least one term in the sequence $(b_n)_n$. This suggests that we could perhaps proceed with a similar argument to that made in part a). The new recurrence relation becomes $b_n + 2 = (b_{n-1} + 2) (b_{n-1} + 1)$, or simplifying: $b_n = b_{n-1}(b_{n-1} + 3)$. The argument should now be almost identical to that in part a), with the observation that $p \ne 3$ becomes the sequence $(b_n)_n$ modulo $3$ is $2, 1, 1, 1, \ldots$.

Is this argument correct? I would be interested in seeing other solutions too, in any case.

Comment: Just on an initial reading, your arguement looks good.

Comment: Conjecture: $a_n\equiv 2\bmod 10$ for any $n\ge 1$

Comment: Proof of the conjecture above. By induction. $ a_0=12\equiv 2\bmod 10$. We have to prove that if $a_n\equiv 2\bmod 10$ then $a_{n+1}\equiv 2\bmod 10$. Indeed $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-a_n$. For the inductive hypothesis $a_n=10k+2$, therefore $a_{n+1}=(10k+2)^2-(10k+2)=100 k^2+30 k+2=10(10k^2+3k)+2$ then $a_{n+1}\equiv 2\bmod 10$. Proved.

Answer (score 1):

the numbers in the sequence are divisible by $2$ and $3$ but are not  divisible by any larger prime $q$ with Legendre symbol $(q,5) = -1.$

For $j\ge1$ We have a sequence $$ t_j = 1, 5, 65, 8645, ...$$
which is $t_{j+1} = t_j (2 t_j + 3) $
Your sequence numbers are $a_j =4 t^2 + 6 t + 2$ and the new multipliers are
$$a_{j+1}/a_j = a_j-1 = 4 t^2 + 6t + 1 = (3t+1)^2 - 5 t^2 $$
As this $a_j - 1$ is primitively represented by $x^2 - 5 y^2,$  it cannot be divisible by any prime $q$ where $q \equiv 2,3 \pmod 5$. Thereby no prime factors $\equiv 2,3\bmod 5$ divide any $a_j$ except the factors $2$ and $3$ of $a_1=12$.

The first few such ``multipliers'' $a_{j+1}/ a_j$ are
$$  11 $$
$$  131  $$
$$ 17291 $$
$$  298995971  $$
$$   89398590973228811  =   8779  \cdot       10079  \cdot     1010341471  $$
$$   7992108067998667938125889533702531 =                  29  \cdot                    59  \cdot                     241  \cdot             2511683491  \cdot       7716660340023314591 $$
$$ 63873791370569400659097694858350356285036046451665934814399129508491 =    109  \cdot    2309  \cdot     1307641  \cdot     1312951  \cdot     4627751  \cdot   19075520521  \cdot   1674514206139655462590242193707851  $$

Notice how each prime factor $p$ has last (decimal) digit $1$ or $9$, and are thereby $p \equiv\pm 1 \pmod{10}$   so  $p \equiv\pm 1 \pmod{5}$

Thus no prime $q > 3$ appears as a factor when   $q \equiv\pm 3 \pmod{5},$   that is $q \equiv\pm 3 \pmod{10},$ so that the last decimal digit of this $q$ is $3$ or $7.$  These ratios are not divisible by $7, 13, 17, 23, 37, 43, 47...$

Comment: Please check my edit.  I am finding that your $t$ sequence starts at $j=1$ not $j=0$, so the bar on additional prime factors $\in \{q: (q|5)=-1\}$ applies only after $a_1=12$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  thanks. I did not check for  index consistency for my $t$ and the original $a$